# How can i set a value with Set-SnmpData with Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, snmp

I'm trying to set the ifAdminStatus value via a powershell script using the SNMP library (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SNMP/1.0.0.1).

When i Get a value using

`Get-SnmpData -Version V2 -IP $target -Community $community_read -OID $oid`

the code works as intended but when i try to set a value using:

`Set-SNMPData -Version 2c -IpAddress $target -Community $community_write -OID $oid -Value $new_value`

this doesn't work.

How can i solve this?

Comment: I tried with another library PoshSNMP (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PoshSNMP/0.2.3) that has a function called "Invoke-SnmpSet" but doesn't work...

Comment: What does _"this doesn't work"_ mean? If you have error mesages, please add them in full (as formatted text in your post)

Comment: with the first library it gets no errors, it just doesn't change the value.

Comment: with the second one the error is the following:
Invoke-SnmpSet : SNMP Set error: Exception calling "Set" with "5" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.

Comment: Using iReasoning Mib Browser I can do set and get without problems using the same data